# bug in analysis service visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssas, analysisservices

I have a problem with visual studio recently.
I installed an analysis service but I can't create a new data source, data source view, cube, and.....
in creating window, I click next but it doesn't do.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated visual studio resolve this problem.